How to pull secrets from kubernetes and refer it as environment variable for spring boot application using helm charts
I am new to helm chart and spring boot application development.
The sensitive details of my spring boot application are stored in AWS secrets manager like below,
basic.auth-role.ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN.[0].username
basic.auth-role.ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN.[0].password
basic.auth-role.ROLE_API_PROXY_CONSUMER.[0].username
basic.auth-role.ROLE_API_PROXY_CONSUMER.[0].password
Using helm charts, I am retrieving these from AWS secrets manager and store it in kubernetes secrets which I am able to do so. PFB snippet,
Snippet from helm values.yaml
externalSecret:
  # Create an external secret resource.
  create: true
  # Name of the secret store.
  name: "integration-hub-service-external-secrets"
  # Target name for the external secret.
  targetName: &externalSecret-targetName integration-hub-service-secrets
  secrets:
    # Define the secrets to be pulled from AWS Secrets Manager.
    - secretKey: &basic_auth-role_ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN_0_username basic_auth-role_ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN_0_username
      remoteRef:
        key: "/DSC/UAT/BLUE/INTEGRATION-HUB-SERVICE"
        property: basic.auth-role.ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN.[0].username
    - secretKey: &basic_auth-role_ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN_0_password basic_auth-role_ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN_0_password
      remoteRef:
        key: "/DSC/UAT/BLUE/INTEGRATION-HUB-SERVICE"
        property: basic.auth-role.ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN.[0].password
    - secretKey: &basic_auth-role_ROLE_API_PROXY_CONSUMER_0_username basic_auth-role_ROLE_API_PROXY_CONSUMER_0_username
      remoteRef:
        key: "/DSC/UAT/BLUE/INTEGRATION-HUB-SERVICE"
        property: basic.auth-role.ROLE_API_PROXY_CONSUMER.[0].username
    - secretKey: &basic_auth-role_ROLE_API_PROXY_CONSUMER_0_password basic_auth-role_ROLE_API_PROXY_CONSUMER_0_password
      remoteRef:
        key: "/DSC/UAT/BLUE/INTEGRATION-HUB-SERVICE"
        property: basic.auth-role.ROLE_API_PROXY_CONSUMER.[0].password

Using helm anchor and alias, I am able to get the value from externalSecret and reference it in env as mentioned below.
Now, the issue here is, I have underscore in 'ROLE_API_PROXY_CONSUMER' and 'ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN'. So, could you please help me on how to mention the environment variable name in this case,
    env:
      - name: "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE"
        value: "local"
      - name: "???"
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: *externalSecret-targetName
            key: *basic_auth-role_ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN_0_username
      - name: "???"
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: *externalSecret-targetName
            key: *basic_auth-role_ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN_0_password


Spring Boot's rules for binding environment variables to Spring properties are included in the Spring Boot documentation: given the property name, replace dots with underscores, remove any dashes, and convert to uppercase.  For list-type values you'd include the index directly in the environment variable name without underscores.
Given these rules, if your Spring property name is
basic.auth-role.ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN.[0].username

then it would be bound from an environment variable
BASIC_AUTHROLE_ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN_0_USERNAME


In your question you discuss YAML anchors.  I'm not quite clear how they'd be used here.  In particular, I'd avoid trying to directly write Kubernetes YAML as Helm values; construct the env: block in your template code instead.  You can generate the name of the Secret as required.  It looks like your ExternalSecret definition is fairly rote, and you may be able to construct this in code as well.

Thank you for answering the query David. I have a query, by having the environment variable as 'BASIC_AUTHROLE_ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN_0_USERNAME', 'ROLE_API_PROXY_ADMIN' - this would read as single value?

Yes, that is one value; if you needed to supply multiple values in a list then you'd need to set multiple environment variables.

If the external secrets controller weren't involved, another possibility could be to write a Java properties file or a YAML file into a ConfigMap or a Secret, but that will work better for things that are known by Helm at deploy time.  Spring Cloud Kubernetes can also directly read properties from Secrets if the service has an appropriate ServiceAccount and Role.
